# Merge Sort Python 2.7x

Tags: python, mergesort

the function merge() is working perfectly but the merge_sort is not,the value of ls and rs is not changing after using merge_sort().Please help in figuring out what is wrong,i have been stuck at it for hours.

```
def merge_sort(arr):


  def merge(sub_arr,p,q):

    L = []
    R = []

    for i in range(p):
        L.append(sub_arr[i])
        #print L

    for i in range(q-p):
        R.append(sub_arr[p+i])
        #print R

    L.append('n')
    R.append('n')

    j=k=0

    for i in range(q):

        if L[j] < R[k] :

            sub_arr[i] = L[j]
            j += 1

        else:

            sub_arr[i] = R[k]
            k += 1


  if len(arr) > 1 :

    ls = arr[:len(arr)/2]
    rs = arr[len(arr)/2:]


    merge_sort(ls)
    #print ls
    merge_sort(rs)
    #print rs



    arr = ls + rs

    #print arr

    merge (arr,len(arr)/2,len(arr))
    #print arr




x = map(int,raw_input('Enter sequence:').strip().split())

merge_sort(x)

print x
```

Comment: Please include some of the output.

Comment: why are you appending `"n"`?

Comment: i am appending 'n' as a check to avoid checking we have reached the end of the list.

Comment: the output is coming out the same as input , on debugging it seems that after using merge_sort(ls) and merge_sort(rs) , the value of ls and rs remains same and it is not the sorted sub-array as expected.

Comment: `arr = ls + rs` throws away the list you were supposed to sort.

Comment: but why ls and rs are not sorted respectively after using merge_sort() ?

Comment: Because you aren't modifying the array you pass into merge_sort, you are modifying the copy created by `arr = ls + rs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that with the line

```
arr = ls + rs
```

You are no longer calling merge on the list passed to merge_sort, but rather calling it on a copy. So the original list isn't being modified. To correct this issue you can have the `merge_sort` function `return arr` at the end, then assign `ls = merge_sort(ls)` (and similar for `rs`). Having done that your code should work.

the correct version is here..

```
def merge_sort(arr):
  def merge(sub_arr,p,q):
    L = []
    R = []
    for i in range(p):
        L.append(sub_arr[i])
    for i in range(q-p):
        R.append(sub_arr[p+i])
    L.append('n')
    R.append('n')
    j=k=0
    for i in range(q):
        if L[j] < R[k] :
            sub_arr[i] = L[j]
            j += 1
        else:
            sub_arr[i] = R[k]
            k += 1
  if len(arr) > 1 :
    ls = arr[:len(arr)/2]
    rs = arr[len(arr)/2:]
    ls = merge_sort(ls)
    rs = merge_sort(rs)    
    arr = ls + rs
    merge (arr,len(arr)/2,len(arr))
  return arr
```

This gives the expected result

```
>>> x = map(int,raw_input('Enter sequence:').strip().split())
Enter sequence:4 5 2 1 3 4 6
>>> y = merge_sort(x)
>>> print x
[4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6]
>>> print y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: but why after using ls and rs are not being modified as in case of merge() where after passing arr it is modified ?